# Kendo UI Grid with custom popup template unbind error

Tags: kendo-ui

Here is a jsfiddle (not mine, but same error).
http://jsfiddle.net/grenal/KGsSL/73/

```
<script id="popup_editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="197" scope="row">Chapter Name</th>
    <td width="403"><label for="chapterName"></label>
    <input type="text" name="chapterName" id="chapterName" data-bind="source: chaptername"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">State</th>
    <td><label for="state"></label>
    <input type="text" name="state" id="state" data-bind="source: state"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <th scope="row">Code</th>
    <td><label for="code"></label>
    <input type="text" name="code" id="code" data-bind="source: code"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Date Added</th>
    <td><label for="dateadded"></label>
    <input type="text" name="dateadded" id="dateadded" data-bind="source: dateadded"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Active</th>
    <td><label for="active"></label>
    <input type="text" name="active" id="active" data-bind="source: active"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Approved</th>
    <td><label for="approved"></label>
    <input type="text" name="approved" id="approved" data-bind="source: approved"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <th scope="row">Chapter Price</th>
    <td><label for="chapterPrice"></label>
    <input type="text" name="chapterPrice" id="chapterPrice" data-bind="source: chapterPrice"></td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <th scope="row">Parent Price</th>
    <td><label for="parentPrice"></label>
    <input type="text" name="parentPrice" id="parentPrice" data-bind="source: parentPrice"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</script>​
```

```
            $(document).ready(function() {


               $("#search").click(function() {
                  // alert("clicked refresh");
                   $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                });                 


                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {


                       transport: {
                                read: {
                                        url: "chaptersJson.cfm",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        data: {q: function() { return $("#chapterName").val();}}
                                },
                            update: {
                                    url: "chaptersJson.cfm?pageaction=Update",
                                    dataType: "json"
                                }

                        },
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "chapterid",
                                fields: {
                                    chapterid: { type:"number" },
                                    chaptername: { type: "string" },
                                    active: {type: "string"},
                                    approved: {type: "string"},
                                    chapterPrice: {type: "string"},
                                    parentPrice: {type:"string"},
                                    code: {type:"string"},
                                    dateadded: {type:"date"},
                                    state: {type:"string"}

                                }
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 25
                    },
                    height: 500,
                    filterable: false,
                    sortable: true,
                    pageable: true,
                    columns: [{field: "chaptername", title: "Chapter", width: 200},
                              {field: "state", title:"State", width: 100},
                              {field: "chapterPrice", title:"Chapter Price", width: 100},
                              {field: "parentPrice", title:"Parent Price", width: 100},
                              {field: "dateadded", title:"Added On", width: 100, template: '#= kendo.toString(dateadded,"MM/dd/yyyy") #'},
                              {command: ["edit"], title:"&nbsp;", width:"210px"}
                    ],
                    editable: {mode: "popup", template: $("#popup_editor").html()}
                });
            });
        </script>
```

When you try to open the popup and then click the X to close or the cancel button, it doesnt close and returns:

Uncaught TypeError: ----------- has no method 'unbind'

I'm basically creating a regular grid with KendoUI, but I wanted a custom popup editor to show more fields that the grid currently does.

Comment: What does your popup_editor html look like?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I updated my code above to include it.  I modeled it after another example I saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the version and the error should disappear (because it's fixed).

Basically you just need to change the script and style references to point to version 913 instead of 710.

e.g.

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.2.913/js/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I updated this morning to the new beta they just posted and it fixed half of my issue.  The window will now close but the console still shows Uncaught TypeError: Object (field value) has no method 'unbind'.  For now at least it closes and I'll work in finishing up my script for updates and adds and see where I can take it from there.

Comment: :) There is official release today so you do not need to use the Beta anymore